# Deciding on LINQ to SQL vs StoredProcs

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

While developing applications, I usually go for Stored Procedures to contain CRUD logic, so as improve performance and maintainability. But after experimenting with LINQ to SQL, I was wondering whether, using **compiled LINQ-to-SQL queries over stored procedures** will that help improve performance?

Comment: Use Entity Framework 4, and you can combine both EF and stored proc support quite nicely!

Comment: @marc_s: You can in [L2S too](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/16/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures.aspx).

Comment: @BlueRaja: yes - to a certain degree. But in L2S, you **cannot** assign one stored proc for DELETE, another for UPDATE, and let L2S handle the normal INSERT operation dynamically. EF4 can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments to both DevSlick and a1ex07, it seems you have a fundamental misunderstanding of what LINQ is.  In order for LINQ queries to allow chaining, like

```
var activePeople = peopleList.Where(o => o.Active).OrderBy(o => o.Ordering).Select(o => o.Name);
```

the execution of the LINQ query must be [delayed](http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2008/04/07/linq-and-delayed-execution.aspx) until it is enumerated:

```
foreach(var person in activePeople)
{
   //If this is LINQ-to-SQL, the query to peopleList has waited until now to request anything from the database
}
```

This means that the query `.Where(o => o.Active).OrderBy(o => o.Ordering).Select(o => o.Name)` is not actually interpreted by your computer until that point as well.  If you run the same query 100 times, that means the computer has to reinterpret that query 100 times.  For LINQ-to-SQL, that means translating the query to SQL 100 times before that SQL is sent to the database each time, even if the SQL is exactly the same every time.

Compiling the query ahead of time causes it to generate the SQL only once, and use that SQL every time the query is called.  This has nothing to do with stored procedures - you would compile a query-to-a-stored-procedure in the same way that you would compile any other query.  Asking *"which gives better performance"* is meaningless, as they are not mutually exclusive.

Though compiling a query sounds like a good thing, in practice interpreting a LINQ query *(usually called "evaluating the expression tree")* takes very very little time compared to actually executing the SQL against the database, so you get very little benefit for compiling the query.  In the meanwhile, the syntax for compiling a query is [atrocious](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896297.aspx):

```
static readonly Func<AdventureWorksEntities, Decimal, IQueryable<SalesOrderHeader>> s_compiledQuery2 = 
    CompiledQuery.Compile<AdventureWorksEntities, Decimal, IQueryable<SalesOrderHeader>>(
        (ctx, total) => from order in ctx.SalesOrderHeaders
                        where order.TotalDue >= total
                        select order);

var orders = s_compiledQuery2.Invoke(context, totalDue);
```

For this reason, it is usually recommended to simply not compile your LINQ-to-SQL queries, because the ratio of code-noise-to-benefit is terrible.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed reply. Now I clearly understand what exactly compiled LINQ to SQL queries mean by.

Answer (score 2):

LINQ to SQL will not improve your performance, because you will be sending each CRUD operation as a string over the wire.

Performance will still be better with Stored Procedures, but ORM's like Linq to SQL usually make development time faster.

Comment: Sorry, you were referring to compiled queries. It seems that the compiled queries may have just as much overhead as the stored procedures, so I wouldn't be able to recommend one over the other.

Comment: Yes what you said is right that LINQ to SQL its sending SQL statements, but what I heard was like, compiled LINQ to SQL queries do make difference on performance front over non-compiled ones.

Comment: Yes, they will be faster than regular Linq to SQL queries, but you still have to write and maintain the code to compile them.

Comment: What I am trying to understand is that, first of all whats the difference between usual LINQ to SQL queries and compiled LINQ to SQL queries. Even though both queries are getting compiled to IL code, so what makes these compiled queries different from the non-compiled ones. Secondly, does compiled queries provide anything more than StoredProcedures on the performance front.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, I can rank performance as following:

1. Stored procedures
2. Native queries (using DBCommand)
3. Linq to entity (compiled query, EF4)
4. Linq to SQL (compiled)
5. Linq to entity (not compiled EF4)
6. Linq to SQL
7. ESQL

   2,3,4 may change their order depends on the nature of the queries, but in general raw sql query is executed fater.

Comment: Thanks for the listing. BTW I feel like every LINQ query is going to be converted to IL once the application is compiled, so what exactly does this compiled LINQ to SQL query mean by?

Comment: @AbrahamJP : check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896297.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399335.aspx for examples.

Comment: I have a feeling this is more from hearsay than experience - if the LINQ-to-SQL or LINQ-to-EF SQL generation engine *(which is the same engine for both, by the way)* is generating decent SQL, the difference between any of these would be imperceptible.

Comment: @BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft. That's can be true. However, with Linq-To-Sql you are limited to SQL Server(at least now)